# Splitting a String into two variables? LUA

Tags: lua, scripting

So in a LUA driver I am writing I am constantly receiving RS232 strings eg;
ZAA1, ZO64, D1 etc. etc. I am after a solution for finding where the string ends, and the Int starts and putting it into two different variables?
I currently am using a while loop with a string.match method inside. is there a better way? Current *Shortened* code below;

```
s = "ZO29"
j = 1
while j <= 64 do
    if (s == string.format("ZO%d", j)) then
        print("Within ZO message")
        inputBuffer = ""
        sendACK()
        break
        
    elseif (s == string.format("ZC%d", j)) then
        inputBuffer = ""
        sendACK() 
        break
    end
    j = j + 1
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a,b=s:match("(.-)(%d+)$")
```

This captures the digits at the end of the string into `b` and the preceding text into `a`.